# Apt-get update/upgrade errors

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

```
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                           
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out
repeats different errors
Err:13 http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/unifi/debian stable InRelease                              
  Could not connect to www.ubnt.com:80 (34.208.224.23), connection timed out [IP: 34.208.224.23 80]
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                              
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Reading package lists... Done                         
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]
 There there are multiple ones here
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The Site REFUSES to let me post the complete error.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of getting 404 errors. This looks more like a network or routing problem (`connection timed out`).

Comment: Can you access the internet (for example with you web browser) from the machine in question?

Comment: Yes I am usig the machine to ask and cmment on the issue noted.